# AWS Java Lambda Function with API Gateway - POJO input and OutputStream output

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm creating a simple AWS Lambda Function in Java that creates and returns a PDF. The function is invoked by an API Gateway. The input is a simple POJO class, but the output should be an `OutputStream` for the file.

For the input, I've tried creating a POJO class and just using the `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` and either works fine. Below is a simple example I used that takes in a input and prints back the query string parameters.

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest( APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, Context context ) {

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
            .withStatusCode(200)
            .withHeaders(Collections.emptyMap())
            .withBody("{\"input\":\"" + input.getQueryStringParameters() + "\"}");
    }

}
```

That works fine, but now I need to alter it to use an `OutputStream` as the the output. How can this be done? I see that I can use the `RequestStreamHandler` and AWS has some [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html) on implementing this. However, that would force my input to be an InputStream, which I'm not sure how that would work with the API Gateway.

How can I serve this PDF back to the client requesting it?

Comment: Can't you just set the type of the response to `OutputStream` (both in the method declaration and in the interface)?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the POJO method of the Lambda handler is a convenience only.  Ultimately, you could do this yourself and use the InputStream/OutputStream Lambda pattern.  Something like:

```
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream,
                          OutputStream outputStream,
                          Context context) throws IOException {
    String inputString = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request = objectMapper.readValue(inputString, APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent.class);

    // do your thing, generate a PDF
    byte[] thePDF = ...
    // create headers
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Content-type", "application/pdf");

    APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().
             .withStatusCode(200)
             .withHeaders(headers)
             .withBody(Base64.Encoder.encode(thePDF))
             .withIsBase64Encoded(Boolean.TRUE);

    outputStream.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response)
                                   .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

However, I'm not convinced that this is really any better.  If you want to return just the PDF without the `APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent` you can but now you'll have to update API Gateway to correctly send the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. In the response builder, `withBody` will only take a String. So it seems like I'll have to convert it there. In the API gateway, I had to disable Lambda Proxy Integration. Also, it appears that the actual PDF is not being sent, but instead, a JSON output. For instance, I'm getting this `{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Content-type":"application/pdf"},"body":"[B@59ec2012","isBase64Encoded":true}` I mostly just need to do a bit more research on my end. But right now, I can't quite figure out how to get the binary data back to the client with the correct content-type.